# Why is this index out of range? And how do I solve it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  If Not TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("ping") Then
      PingSplit = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    End If

    Select Case True
      Case TextBox1.Text.Contains("ping")
        ' I get an IndexOutOfRange Exception was unhandled on below line
        If PingSplit(0) Is Nothing Or PingSplit(1) Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox("Invalid Ping IP!")
        Else
          ListBox1.Items.Add(GetPingMs(PingSplit(1)))
          PingSplit(0) = vbNullString
          PingSplit(1) = vbNullString
        End If
End Sub
```

However, I cannot get the code to work when I simply type in "ping", "ping www.google.com[1] " works perfectly, however it will not work with just ping. The idea is that I type in ping "x", the code splits the ping and gets the address (x), and then uses the address in GetPingMs function, (getpingMsg(pingsplit(1)), however I get an IndexOutOfRange Exception.

Comment: `Select Case` is not necessary here. Just use an `If`. Or even better - `If Not TextBox1.Text.Contains("ping") Then Return`. You have less indentation - it's easier to read your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an exception because you're trying to de-reference an array element that doesn't exist.  If all you type is "ping" then your `PingSplit` array is only going to have one element, at index 0.  But you're trying to reference a second element:

```
PingSplit(1)
```

You need to check the length of the array before you try to reference elements which may not be there.  Something like this might work (my VB is a bit rusty, I'm not 100% sure that this is how you check the length):

```
If PingSplit.Length < 2 Then
    MsgBox("Invalid Ping IP!")
End If
```

Basically, any time you're going to reference items in a collection, you should always do some checking on the collection first to make sure those items exist at all.